# 2 LEFT OUTER JOIN on the same table freezes server

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run a query on table 'apst_mailings' storing the content of each newsletter we send to our subscribers. Each time we attempt to send the email to an individual we insert a row in apst_mailings_accuses reporting the time and state of the sending, and the ID of the newletter. I wanna list the newsletters and count the total sent and successfully sent for each.

```
    SELECT m.id AS code_mailing, 
    COUNT(a.adh_code) AS num, COUNT(b.adh_code) AS succes
    FROM apst_mailings AS m
        LEFT OUTER JOIN apst_mailings_accuses AS a
            ON a.id_mailing = m.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN apst_mailings_accuses AS b
            ON b.id_mailing = m.id
            AND b.etat = 'succes'
    GROUP BY m.id
```

And it simply hangs the server forever. I have tried each join in separated queries and it worked without problem:

```
// Counts the email sent per mailing
    SELECT m.id AS code_mailing, 
    COUNT(a.adh_code) AS num
    FROM apst_mailings AS m
        LEFT OUTER JOIN apst_mailings_accuses AS a
            ON a.id_mailing = m.id
    GROUP BY m.id

    SELECT m.id AS code_mailing, 
    COUNT(b.adh_code) AS succes
    FROM apst_mailings AS m
        LEFT OUTER JOIN apst_mailings_accuses AS b
            ON b.id_mailing = m.id
            AND b.etat = 'succes'
    GROUP BY m.id
```

I could split my query but the reason why it doesn't work really bothers me. Can anyone explain please?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the query? Why join one table twice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can what you want in a much simpler way by using a single join and using `SUM` to perform a conditional count.

```
SELECT
   m.id AS code_mailing, 
   COUNT(a.adh_code) AS num,
   SUM(a.etat = 'succes') AS succes
FROM apst_mailings AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN apst_mailings_accuses AS a
ON a.id_mailing = m.id
GROUP BY m.id
```

But the reason why your query doesn't work is because you're joining **ALL** the rows in subquery *a* with **ALL** the matching rows in subquery *b* in a huge cross join. This could generate a huge temporary result set, which is presumably why the query takes forever to terminate. And even if it did terminate, your counts would be completely off - they would be the product of the two counts.

To solve it do the `GROUP BY` first. Then `JOIN` the result of that to your main table.

```
SELECT
   m.id AS code_mailing, 
   IFNULL(a.num, 0) AS num,
   IFNULL(b.succes, 0) AS succes
FROM apst_mailings AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT id_mailing, COUNT(adh_code) AS num
   FROM apst_mailings_accuses 
   GROUP BY id_mailing
) a
ON a.id_mailing = m.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT id_mailing, COUNT(adh_code) AS succes
    FROM apst_mailings_accuses
    WHERE etat = 'succes'
    GROUP BY id_mailing
) b
ON b.id_mailing = m.id
```

Comment: What do you mean by group first? Where should I put the GROUP BY?

Comment: Waow! Cheers! I love the second one. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Nabab: I changed it so the second one comes frst, since I think it's probably a better approach. It doesn't check for NULL values of adh_code, but that can be fixed if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I just added it: `IFNULL( SUM(a.etat = 'succes'), 0 ) AS succes`.